# Alexa AMAZON.FallbackIntent for other than English and French

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I don't understand how Alexa handles unmatched utterances. There is a [AMAZON.FallbackIntent](https://developer.amazon.com/fr/docs/custom-skills/standard-built-in-intents.html#fallback) available only in English and French. So for my French skills, after submission they reported :

> While interacting with your skill we determined that, in certain cases, your skill does not respond with a clear and audible response to some of the inputs provided. We do not allow skills to respond in an inaudible or unclear manner to customers.
>
> Upon providing long irrelevant input to the skill in an open session, the skill should end the session post 8 seconds or provide a verbal prompt understanding that the audio input is irrelevant. Expected Behavior: Your skill should respond in an audible and clear manner to all customer input by providing instructions on what to do next.

I don't understand how to handle this feedback

Comment: How do you react on the FallbackIntent? Are you ending the session or give a proper reply that you did not understandt the user?

Comment: there is no such intent for the FRENCH language. I don't understand how alexa reacts with un matched utterances

Comment: mhh I know the issue when all the feature are not available in preferred language :-). I remember when there was no Fall Back Intent in german that I just had a default reply in my code when there was not a known intent sent from Amazon to me. You could use the TEST in developer console and look into JSON how the intent is filled? Is it null? Than you could react on that in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: FallbackIntent is now also available in French, Italian, Spanish and Japanese

`AMAZON.FallbackIntent` is only available for English and German locales. The certification feedback means that you're not handling out-of-domain utterances gracefully (this can happen even on skills where the locale supports the fallback intent).
If the feedback in question is for the French version of your skill (i.e. you're handling this correctly in the English version thanks to the fallback intent availability) your only option until fallback become available in other locales is to follow the advice I'm giving here:

[How to fallback into error when reprompt is processed in Alexa Skill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53333910/how-to-fallback-into-error-when-reprompt-is-processed-in-alexa-skill/53356675#53356675)